# how to fetch the list of values from radio button?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am working on selenium and python. I am unable to select the radio button. I want to  add the values in a list. and iterate and click on the specific radio button.

```
 def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com")


        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[normalize-space()='ROUND TRIP']").click()
```

[image]

error

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[normalize-space()='ROUND TRIP']"}

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to iterate through them.

Just target the correct element, your xpath could look like this:

```
//li[@data-cy='roundTrip']
```

One of the problems with your current xpath is you're trying to find an 'a' element, where the fake radio buttons are actually 'li' elements.